# Google Script to email individual progress reports to students

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I work at a high school and would like to write a script to email individual progress reports to about 1400 students.  I can save them in a folder on my Google Drive as .pdf and then email them (Gmail) to all our students.  I would like to use the student's ID as a unique identifier.

I am not a programmer and just need direction on how to get this done.  Any help is appreciated.  I was searching the site and found some scripts that email attachments but I couldn't find anything that emails specific files to specific individuals; like individualized progress reports.

Thank you.

I found this code and tried to modify it to fit my needs but it doesn't send out any emails.  I have a Google Sheet with two columns: FileName, email address and three rows of data.  I also have the corresponding files saved on my drive.

```
function sendEmailsTest2() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;
var numRows = 3;
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var intakenumber = row[0];
    var emailaddress = row[1];
}
  
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(intakenumber);
var attachments = [];
while (files.hasNext()) {
var file = files.next();
attachments.push(file.getAs(MimeType.PDF));
Logger.log(attachments)
var message = "Hello. Your Progress Report is attached";
var subject = "Progress Report";
var attachment = (attachments);
    MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: emailaddress,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: message,
        attachments: attachments
        })
}
```

}`

Comment: Hey if you can share a sample data sheet or an image of what data it to be exported or emailed I think I can help you out as I am also working on emailing PDFs from my sheets.

Comment: @Harsh - thanks for responding.  I would create a Google Sheet with two columns: studentID and studentEmail.  Then I would add the .pdf reports in a folder on my drive and name them by the student ID.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd break this problem into 2 parts - first make sure that data is actually being read from the spreadsheet, second - make sure email sending flow works properly. So the question is, with which part exactly do you have a problem? If you are not sure - then you're probably better off paying someone to do this task for you - and I don't say it in mean spirit, it's just this task might have low ROI for you to spend your time on it.

Comment: There's might be a number of reasons this cannot work. For once, you are declaring the `emailaddress` in a loop, but you're using it after the loop, so it can only send an email to a single specific address, at most (the one in `B4`, it looks like). Also, you're looking for files with the same name as the value of `A4`. Do you have files with this name in Drive? If not, the script won't enter the `while` block and of course no email will be sent. Also, do you really only want to send 3 emails? (because you're only iterating through 3 rows).

Comment: If you clarify my previous concerns, I'd consider posting an answer explaining in more detail where your code is failing and will provide a working code snippet.

Comment: Can you clarify that do you want to generate pdf's from data in spreadsheet or just want to email the pdf's stored in drive folder. I am also editing your code and reposting it with the workable code as per my knowledge.

Comment: @Harsh - I just want to email the pdf's stored in drive folder.  I don't need to generate them from data in spreadsheet.  Thanks.

Comment: @ego - thank you for your comments.  I really appreciate you being real with me and I can see that you are not being mean spirited.  The truth of the matter is that I am trying to learn as I go.  I know I have a long way to go but I am going to take it one day at a time.  Thank you.

Comment: @Iamblichus - thanks for commenting.  I do have the files with the same name stored in my drive in a specific folder.  At the moment, I only have 3 emails because I want to test it with a few staff members in my school before I send it out to the student body. (1400 students).  Thanks again for your comments.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL FOR YOU HELP.  This works perfectly.  I appreciate this so much.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `emailaddress` and `intakenumber` in a loop, but you're using them after the loop. Because of this, it will at most send a single email, corresponding to the last row in the range.

Therefore, the code should be something like this instead:

```
function sendEmailsTest2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var intakenumber = row[0];
    var emailaddress = row[1];
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(intakenumber); // Might have to be changed to: var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(intakenumber + ".pdf");
    var attachments = [];    
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      attachments.push(file.getAs(MimeType.PDF));
      var message = "Hello. Your Progress Report is attached";
      var subject = "Progress Report";
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: emailaddress,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: message,
        attachments: attachments
      });
    }
  }
}
```

#### Important:

Also, make sure that column A contains valid file names, **including extensions**, if they exist (for example, in case of a `.PDF`, the cell value should be `file_name.pdf`). Otherwise, the file won't be found by `getFilesByName`.

Either this or edit the corresponding line to `var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(intakenumber + ".pdf");` instead.

I think this might be the reason you didn't receive any email before.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```js
function generatePdf() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = ss.getRange('A1:B').getValues();
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  // Get folder containing spreadsheet and PDF
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var pdfName = data[i][0] + '.pdf';
    var email = data[i][1];
    // Subject of email message
    const subject = `Progress Report Attachement: ${pdfName}`;
    // Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image
    const body = "<p>Hello,</p><p>Your Progress Report is attached";
    var files = folder.getFilesByName(pdfName);
    if (files.hasNext()) {
      if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
        GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
          htmlBody: body,
          attachments: [files.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
        });
    };
  };

  sourceSpreadsheet.toast("Reports Emailed ", "Success");

}
```

I hope now you can email all the PDF's in the drive folder where your spreadsheet and PDF's are stored.